# Чтение из файла

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток! Прошу подсказать мне по поводу занесения данных в файл, и главное - чтение из файла. Функцию `fscanf` я знаю, но её вызов почему-то даёт мне не то, что нужно. Хочу уточнить, `fprintf` - заносит данные в файл, а `fscanf` - копирует из файла в переменную? Вот моя программа:

```
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ro.txt", "w");
    printf("vozrast? \n");    
    scanf ("%d", &K);    
    fprintf(fp, "%d", K);    
    fp=fopen("ro.txt", "r");      
    while (!feof(fp))     
    {
       fscanf(fp, "%d", &new_K); 
    }   
    printf("%d", new_K);
```

Как я понимаю, число должно из блокнота записываться в `new_k`, однако туда почему-то записывается и выводится на экран посторонее значение. Подскажите, плз, в чём я не права?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая штука -- системная каретка. Так вот, сначала Вы пишете в файл, каретка идет к концу файла. Затем Вы читаете из файла, но каретка-то уже в конце файла. Чтоб не закрывать-открывать файл десятки тысяч раз, используйте функцию fseek() (погуглите насчет параметров и подробностей). Сначала пишете в файл, затем вызываете, например, fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET); и затем читаете, но уже с начала файла.

Comment: Да, но тогда пусть открывает с параметром "w+"

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Если получилось, то ответ полагается принять).

Comment: сделано) спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка лежащая на поверхности в том, что вы не закрыв файл (FILE *fp), открытый на запись снова открываете его на чтение **используя ту же самую переменную**. Просто добавьте fclose(fp) перед вторым fopen().

Дело в том, что stdio реализует буферизацию вывода. Вы вызвали fprintf(), данные попали в буфер, но на диск (точнее в буфера ОС) их никто не переписал. Они переместятся туда в следующих случаях

1) записали много данных (больше размера буфера в stdio)

2) вызвали функцию fflush()

3) выполнили fclose().

После этого они могут быть прочитаны.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, в какой fp записывается переменная. Чтобы записать что-то в файл, надо его сначала открыть для записи, получить поток, записать туда и закрыть. Потом снова открыть для чтения и т.д.

Comment: FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("ro.txt", "w");
прошу прощения)) вот первые две строки. Конечно, я открывала файл, просто для экономии места не добавила этих строк

Comment: Ну так сначала закройте его, потом снова откройте для чтения.